# The Preview in XCode Keeps Changing the Width

Tags: xcode, swiftui, geometry, xcode12

Somehow the preview on XCode 12.5.1 keeps changing the width of the preview so it flickers, sometimes from the normal width of the preview to a narrow width of the preview.

I have followed the tabs tutorial from [Sean Allen](https://youtu.be/tnNFoZ7CkP8), and I will put the code he used down below. Although the flickering occurs on all tab views, I am thinking that the code used for a slider(the second code down below) in a tab view is the cause because this code has Geometry. The other tab views(which I am not including) only have the default 'Hello World' code.

Since I'm a beginner, it would be nice if the explanation is easy to understand. Thanks in advance!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        TabView {
            
            Statistic()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar")
                }
            
            Clock()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "timer")
                }
            
            Rank()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.3")
                }
            
        }
        .accentColor(Color(hue: 0.541, saturation: 0.691, brightness: 0.817))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
extension CGFloat {
    func map(from: ClosedRange<CGFloat>, to: ClosedRange<CGFloat>) -> CGFloat {
        let result = ((self - from.lowerBound) / (from.upperBound - from.lowerBound)) * (to.upperBound - to.lowerBound) + to.lowerBound
        return result
    }
}

struct CustomSlider: View {
    
    @Binding var value: CGFloat
    
    @State var lastOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var range: ClosedRange<CGFloat>
    var leadingOffset: CGFloat = 5
    var trailingOffset: CGFloat = 5
    
    var knobSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .frame(height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.55, saturation: 0.326, brightness: 1.0))
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                    )
                HStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                        .frame(width: self.knobSize.width, height: self.knobSize.height)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .offset(x: self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset)))
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    
                                    if abs(value.translation.width) < 0.1 {
                                        self.lastOffset = self.$value.wrappedValue.map(from: self.range, to: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset))
                                    }
                                    
                                    let sliderPos = max(0 + self.leadingOffset, min(self.lastOffset + value.translation.width, geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset))
                                    let sliderVal = sliderPos.map(from: self.leadingOffset...(geometry.size.width - self.knobSize.width - self.trailingOffset), to: self.range)
                                    
                                    self.value = sliderVal
                                }
                        )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80, height: 30)
        .padding(.bottom, 37)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you have posted won't compile because you left out the views for the `TabView` in `ContentView' and included `CustomSlider` which is not actually used in your `ContentView` struct.

Comment: @Yrb , thank you for the information! I'll keep that in mind. On the happy note, I'm not sure how but I think deleting some parts and waiting for XCode to update it helped, and the problem's fixed.